# Error when ALTER TABLE - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alter-table

I'm using SQL Server and trying to change an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE [Users] 
(
    [User_ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [UserName] [NVARCHAR](30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, -- the only change is "UNIQUE"
    [UserEmail] [NVARCHAR](30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,  -- the only change is "UNIQUE"
    [Password] [NVARCHAR](30) NOT NULL,
)
```

And get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

I'm changing the syntax each time but still get this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1

What is the problem ?

Comment: Simply, the syntax is wrong, check **[ALTER TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**, you need just to add 2 constraints.

Comment: @Sami I tried with `alter column` but its the same error. its a huge page you sent there

Comment: its an old table not new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot add Unique Key constraint at column level. Unique Key Constraint are defined at table level.

You may alter table to add Unique key in below ways.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (column1, column2, ... column_n);
```

for e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE Users
ADD CONSTRAINT Users_Unique UNIQUE (UserName, UserEmail);
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add a `UNIQUE` constraint as

```
ALTER TABLE [Users] 
ADD CONSTRAINT U_UserName UNIQUE(UserName),
    CONSTRAINT U_UserEmail UNIQUE(UserEmail);
```

Comment: why the addition? it is highly likely that both user name and user email need to be unique independently rather than duplicates of either being accepted as long as the combination is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for `ALTER TABLE` is completely wrong - if you just want to add `UNIQUE` to the two columns in question - use this:

```
ALTER TABLE [Users] 
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Users_UserName UNIQUE (UserName);

ALTER TABLE [Users] 
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Users_UserEmail UNIQUE (UserEmail);
```

Read all about [the `ALTER TABLE` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on Docs@Microsoft

Comment: I changed it but I get the same error -  `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNIQUE'.`

Answer (score 1):

`Alter` are different with `Create` Statement..

*Definition* :

> ALTER TABLE statement is used to add, delete, or modify columns in an
>   existing table also used to add and drop various constraints on an
>   existing table

You can check here for demo it is works : [`DEMO`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f6924b5f2c6af58a9fb1e8767423ab6e)

Comment: Glad if help you @sup.DR .. You could choose answer whose fit with your question.. :)